# Curvature of level-sets of CG1 function

Tags: finite-element

Let us have simplicial mesh and continuous function $u$ which is piece-wise linear and non-constant on every cell. Then normal vector to level-sets of $u$ is given $$\mathbf{n}=\frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|}$$ and is piece-wise constant function. What is then possible definition of curvature $\kappa$ which would be for $u\in{\cal C}^2$ $$\kappa = \mathrm{div}\,\mathbf{n}.$$ This definition is not suitable as it yields $\kappa$ being zero in every cell and a multiple of Dirac $\delta$ on every facet.

In conclusion: **what is a suitable finite-element space for $\kappa$ and weak formulation for $\kappa = \mathrm{div}\,\mathbf{n}$ with given piece-wise constant $\mathbf{n}$**?

**EDIT**: I got another idea: first **project $\mathbf{n}$ on some $H(\mathrm{div})$-conforming space**; then it is no problem calculating $\mathrm{div}\,\mathbf{n}$ directly. I did some numerical experiments with $u$ being projection of
$$ u^\mathrm{exact} = (1+x)(1+y) $$
to CG1 (continuous, piece-wise linear) on domain $\Omega=(0,1)\times(0,1)$. Exact curvature for $u^\mathrm{exact}$ is
$$ \kappa^\mathrm{exact} = \frac{-2(1+x)(1+y)}{[(1+x)^2+(1+y)^2]^{3/2}} .$$
Taking Raviart-Thomas degree 1 space (piece-wise linears, continuous on facet midpoints) or CG1 space as space for $\mathbf{n}$ method seems to converge in norms but with annoying wiggles on $\partial\Omega$. Here is calculated $\kappa$
[image: $\kappa$]

and error $\kappa-\kappa^\mathrm{exact}$
[image: $\kappa-\kappa^\mathrm{exact}$]

Can you see the problem?

Comment: I typically try to project derivatives onto one order lower spaces to get some averaging and avoid the wiggles. Depending on your purposes, you might try using piecewise constants for $\kappa$.

Comment: Well, that's what I did - $\mathbf{n}\in$CG1/RT1 implies $\kappa\in$DG0. I think the problem may be that during projection: DG0$\rightarrow$RT1/CG1: $\frac{\nabla u}{|\nabla u|}\mapsto\mathbf{n}$ boundary values are subject to sorcery. I'm gonna try ignore them now.

Comment: OK, I didn't want to try to read anything into what you did. You could easily try to project back into the same space (which could cause a lot more trouble). Also, you plotted something that looks CG1, so I wasn't sure.

Comment: Yes, this is boring post:) And yes, plots are misleading. This is FEniCS deficiency, it plots only CG1 interpolations:(

Comment: I don't think it's boring! Just trying to be perfectly clear about things. I think you're right that there's some issues near the boundaries. What happens as you refine the mesh? Do the errors grow or shrink?

Comment: Error stays approximately same with refinement. This is nature of the projection: DG0$\rightarrow$CG1 or RT1 (with spaces on the same mesh). This is something like Gibbs phenomenon. You can see it also in 1D when CG1 function $f=x$ is projected to DG0 and then back to CG1. The maximum error of the derivative of the resulting function also does not depend on fineness of uniform mesh, see figures [mesh10](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~blecj6am/dolfin_plot_2.png) [mesh100](http://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~blecj6am/dolfin_plot_3.png) Possible solution could be non-uniform mesh and/or dual mesh.